# iphone sdk/mac - problem with sockets

Tags: iphone, macos, sockets, port

My program consists of 2 parts  - A server socket running on a different thread, and a client to test the server. I'm 99.9% sure that the server is correctly written (because I have tested it with a client socket), and all it does is returns "hello world" as a response. The server sits on port 3490.

Now what I tried to do is to call the server in the following way:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://localhost:3490"]];
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(msg);
```

But I get no response. I suspect that the problem is with the address http://localhost:3490

This problem appears on the iphone an on mac.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Alex

I have this problem on the iphone and on mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that localhost resolves to an IPv6 address. Try using `http://127.0.0.1:3490/` instead first before turning to `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you almost certainly want to be using `+[NSURL URLWithString:]` instead of `+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`.

Second, since `-[NSData initWithContentsOfURL:]` hides so much of what's going on to make the connection, you might consider switching to an `NSURLConnection` you manage yourself, at least temporarily. The delegate methods it uses will give you a lot more visibility to / control over the various stages of the process. (As well as not blocking the thread on which you're running this code.)